# Does child process execute both prints?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, parent-child

What would be the output? I'm confused, it's 2  or 3 but which one I'm not sure. Can you help?

```
main() 
{
    printf("hello\n");

    if(fork() == 0)
        printf("hello\n");
}
```

Comment: What did you find?  What happens when you pipe the output through `cat`, or redirect it to a file?

Comment: Why will people cut and paste the code into a SO question but not into their editor of choice and compile the &*^%$ thing to get a solid answer!

Comment: While his concern is `why` code behaves so, he is welcome.

Comment: @Xaqron No. question is "WHAT would be the output".

Comment: @John3136: Then he could simply paste it into` GCC` instead of `SO` and get the result.

Comment: @Xaqron That is my point!

Answer (score 2):

`if` statement is gonna be evaluated after forking so each process would run it with it's own return value which is zero for child process and non-zero (PID) for parent so there would be 1 `hello` at this point.

Plus the first `hello` at the top of your code you get total of 2 `hello`s at terminal.